# Source "truffle/Console.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Tags: truffle, console

after install `truffle -g`

try to run console.log by import "truffle/Console.sol"
from

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-logger-example

get error on import line - not found.
how can i import this file?

`Source "truffle/Console.sol" not found: File import callback not supported`

try to install truffle again in my folder but nothing happen.

try to find the source code in GitHub to import manually - didn't find

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub thread points to the "Consol.sol" file being removed from the project repo.. See here: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-logger-example/issues/3#issuecomment-916759451